# WPF ToolTip - How to show more than once

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a slider with a tooltip:

```
<Slider x:Name="m_slider" ToolTipService.BetweenShowDelay="0" ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="500" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="9999999">
    <Slider.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>
            <StackPanel>
                <!--  .... -->
            </StackPanel>
        </ToolTip>
    </Slider.ToolTip>
</Slider>
```

When I click the slider, its tooltip disapears (which is ok). But when I move again the mouse over the slider it doesn't show up again. Only if I leave the slider and move back with the mouse cursor, tool tip appears again.

Is it possible (w/o using IsOpen property) to re-show the tool tip after it disappears (as if I went out and in again with the mouse)?

Comment: Why without the IsOpen property?

Answer (score 0):

You could wire up one of the sliders events to create a popup window with the control's tooltip as its contents.